# SSL between onion and web server

Tags: configuration, onion-services, security

I have seen recommendations to run the hidden service and the web server on different servers. I currently have the hidden service running in a second vm than the nginx server which points to an upstream Apache server. For better security I want to move the hidden service to a different server, and point it to the nginx server. Would the communication between the hidden service and the nginx server be encrypted? I don't think it would be. How should I achieve encryption between both of the servers?

Comment: Why not have them communicate across a hidden service?

Answer (score 0):

The communication between the two web server are not encrypted. Instead of going through the trouble of create SSL certs just use a reverse SSH connection and proxy_pass in Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Tor is like STunnel, i.e. it's working as a tunnel mapper - and the data that are going out of the Tor are *as they sent*, and in the case of HTTP - it's a plaintext. Your VM setup is *completely separated* from Tor setup itself, so - if you need to make it encrypted and work as simply as it can - use STunnel :) Don't forget to set the verification level to 3 and just enjoy your secure ride! Feel free to ask for more details if you need them!